# How to convert RTMP to mp4 On The Fly with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

i want to ask about live streaming, i have wowza server and used rtmp protocol in web client, the question is how to compatible in all device like desktop and mobile, i used ffmpeg, but how to change rtmp to mp4 on the fly? what type command in ffmpeg? i want to used protocol http not rtmp or rtsp, thanks.

Regards,
Panji

Answer (score 5):

If you want live http streaming (HLS), then you should use wowza's `cupertinostreamingpacketizer` in the `<LiveStreamPacketizers>` list, and point non-rtmp clients at `http://your-server:1935/live/yourstream/playlist.m3u8`. No need for ffmpeg. Often the HLS packetizer is enabled by default on wowza, so just try going to that URL in an html5+h264 capable browser. Bear in mind your encoding software must encode as h264, not the v6 codec.

Your HLS stream will be around 30s - 1 minute behind the rtmp stream. If you want the stream to be in sync across devices, consider using HDS (`sanjosestreamingpacketizer`) instead of rtmp, and pointing your HDS-capable flash player at `http://your-server:1935/live/yourstream/manifest.f4m`.

If you want to record a live stream as an mp4 for later playback, you can use wowza's in-built recording API - see http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?123#userinterface.

Alternatively, you can use rtmpdump (generally available as a package on most unix systems) to grab the rtmp stream, then ffmpeg to convert once it's down:

```
rtmpdump -q --rtmp "rtmp://your-server:1935/live/" --playpath yourstream -o yourstream.flv --live
ffmpeg -i yourstream.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy yourstream.mp4 </dev/null
ffmpeg -i yourstream.mp4 -vframes 1 yourstream.jpg </dev/null
```

The first ffmpeg command converts to an mp4, the second grabs the first frame and saves as a .jpg so you can use it as your poster frame.